How to make power query credentials user friendly for refreshing query in an excel file
I wrote some files to simplify users. They select a file and some macro and power query will refresh and return them the information.
For a few of them, I need to refresh some data that is stored in a sharepoint.
When a new user run the macro that will refresh the queries, it bugs because the credentials are not filled.
So I need to explain them how to open power query and set their credentials to connect to the sharepoint.
Is there anyway that this could pop-up if no credentials are setup or wrong ? So it would be easier for the users ?
I except the connection refresh to happen automatically or get a user messagebox or input box to fill their credentials instead of failing.

Anytime I've ever distributed an Excel file that used an external data source (i.e. ODBC), Excel has always automatically prompted the user to enter their credentials. To my knowledge the credentials should be stored per connection string in the Windows Credential Manager (or other manager), and if they're unavailable it should automatically prompt the user. I feel there is some other misconfiguration in your setup that may require more info, but perhaps someone else may know more.
